# How to change Walker_Nav class_Menu in wp(customize menu)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to customise menu in wp. I want to add`<span></span>`
 to main menues only.but if i do so,it will be applied to sub menu
 also:

```
$item_output = $args->before;
$item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
$item_output .= '<span></span>';
/** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
$item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
$item_output .= '</a>';
$item_output .= $args->after;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try something like this

$class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
            if($depth>0){
                $span='<span></span>';

            }
$item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $span;
        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;
```